# No port 'a' on instance

Tags: vhdl, vivado

so I am working on the students labs from the xilinx website. I've been trying to look through many different examples online but I can't seem to find one to help fix my problem. I'm getting the following errors when trying to synthesize my code. I've tried mostly switching to different letters and cases. Even the sample code in the lab pdf had syntax errors for declaring components. Any help would be great thanks.

Below is a list of errors i'm getting.

> [Synth 8-485] no port 'a' on instance ["C:/Nexys 4 >Projects/lab1_3_1/lab1_3_1.srcs/sources_1/new/mux_2bit_2_to_1.vhd":67]
>
> [Synth 8-485] no port 'a' on instance ["C:/Nexys 4 >Projects/lab1_3_1/lab1_3_1.srcs/sources_1/new/mux_2bit_2_to_1.vhd":67]
>
> [Synth 8-485] no port 'b' on instance ["C:/Nexys 4 >Projects/lab1_3_1/lab1_3_1.srcs/sources_1/new/mux_2bit_2_to_1.vhd":67]
>
> [Synth 8-485] no port 'b' on instance ["C:/Nexys 4 >Projects/lab1_3_1/lab1_3_1.srcs/sources_1/new/mux_2bit_2_to_1.vhd":67]
>
> [Synth 8-485] no port 'b' on instance ["C:/Nexys 4 >Projects/lab1_3_1/lab1_3_1.srcs/sources_1/new/mux_2bit_2_to_1.vhd":60]

Below is my code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity mux_2bit_2_to_1 is
    Port ( x0 : in STD_LOGIC;
           x1 : in STD_LOGIC;
           y0 : in STD_LOGIC;
           y1 : in STD_LOGIC;
           s : in STD_LOGIC;
           m0 : out STD_LOGIC;
           m1 : out STD_LOGIC);
end mux_2bit_2_to_1;

architecture Behavioral of mux_2bit_2_to_1 is
    component and2 port
    (
        i0, i1 : in STD_LOGIC;
        o : out STD_LOGIC
    ); end component;
    
    component or2 port
    (
        i0, i1 : in STD_LOGIC;
        o : out STD_LOGIC
    ); end component;

    component INV port
    (
        a : in STD_LOGIC;
        b : out STD_LOGIC                                         LINE 60
    ); end component;

    signal c, d, f, g, h : STD_LOGIC;

begin

inv_comp1 : INV port map (                                       LINE 67
    a=>s, 
    b=>c
);
and_comp1 : and2 port map (
    i0 => x1, 
    i1 => c,
    o => d
);
and_comp2 : and2 port map (
    i0 => x0, 
    i1 => c,
    o => g
);
and_comp3 : and2 port map (
    i0 => y1, 
    i1 => s,
    o => f
);
and_comp4 : and2 port map (
    i0 => y0, 
    i1 => c,
    o => h
);
or_comp1 : or2 port map (
    i0 => d,
    i1 => f,
    o => m1
);
or_comp2 : or2 port map (
    i0 => f,
    i1 => h,
    o => m0
);
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: A component instantiation associates formals (the signals declared in an entity) with actuals (signals in it's environment).  A component declaration is analogous to a function prototype although also providing formal names. The library containing an analyzed entity INV and any matching architectures isn't apparent here. Does you component declaration port names  match the entity port names? For instance in unisim INV.vhd shows the ports named `I` and `O` respectively while AND2.vhdl matches your and2 component declaration albeit in a different order requiring formal association.

Comment: The labs don't really explain too much about it and I'm mostly learning by example right now. After changing a and b to I and O that fixed the problem. Thank you for your help. Where do i find the library that includes INV.vhdl and the others?

Comment: I had the VHDL source for unisim library sitting around from ISE. A library should show up in a context clause (before you're entity declaration). Is there a library declaration or use statement you culled from you example in the first 30 lines? I'd hate to think Vivado has implied context. This may also demonstrate why you should consider simulating before synthesizing. Syntax and semantic errors tend to be better explained in simulators than synthesis tools which tend to complain in a hardware 'centric manner.  See Vivado Design Suite User's Guide Logic Simulation (UG900).

Comment: I appreciate all your help. It says                                                                 library IEEE; use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;